# How can I convert github flavored markdown to HTML?

Tags: github, markdown, redcarpet

I know github has released the Redcarpet gem for converting markdown to HTML but as far as I have seen it doesn't support (or recognize) Github flavored markdown such as

`javascript
var x = 1;`

Anyone know if there is a gem (or some way with redcarpet) to handle the github flavored syntax, specifically I am interested in the syntax highlighting.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now better to use github-markdown gem.

```ruby
GitHub::Markdown.render(content)
```

Comment: thanks for the comment, glad to see this gem is available and being updated.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Redcarpet for converting markdown code to HTML. Here you have two examples extracted from Redcarpet project tests

````ruby
def test_compat_api_knows_fenced_code_extension
  text = "```ruby\nx = 'foo'\n```"
  html = RedcarpetCompat.new(text, :fenced_code).to_html
  html_equal "<pre><code class=\"ruby\">x = 'foo'\n</code></pre>", html
end

def test_compat_api_ignores_gh_blockcode_extension
  text = "```ruby\nx = 'foo'\n```"
  html = RedcarpetCompat.new(text, :fenced_code, :gh_blockcode).to_html
  html_equal "<pre><code class=\"ruby\">x = 'foo'\n</code></pre>", html
end
````

I hope this answers your question

Answer (score 0):

GitHub publishes the [`github-markup`](https://github.com/github/markup) gem, which can convert markup to HTML. You can either install it as a gem:

```bash
$ gem install github-markup
```

Or, if you are running Ubuntu, install it using `apt`:

```bash
$ sudo apt install ruby-github-markup
```

`Github-markup` can be used in a Ruby program and from the command line.

### Ruby Program Usage

Unfortunately, the code examples of how to use `github-markup` that are shown in the `README` are under-documented.
However, the [command line source code](https://github.com/github/markup/blob/master/bin/github-markup) is a complete working example of how to use `github-markup` in a Ruby program.

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

$LOAD_PATH.unshift File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__)) + "/../lib"
require 'github/markup'

if ARGV.size < 1
  print "usage: #{File.basename($0)} FILE [ FILES ... ]\n"
  exit 1
end

sources = []

ARGV.each { |s|
  begin
    file = File.open( s, "r" )
    sources.push [ s, file ]
  rescue Exception => e
    $stderr.print "error: #{e.message}\n"
    exit 1
  ensure
  end
}

sources.each { |name, file|
  print GitHub::Markup.render( name, file.read )
  file.close
}
```

### Command Line Usage

Here is an example of using `github-markup` in a command line:

```bash
$ github-markup README.md
```

### Copying HTML Output to the System Clipboard

I normally work in WSL. Here is a convenient way to copy the generated HTML to the clipboard:

```bash
$ github-markup README.md | clip.exe
```

On a generic X11 terminal, you could accomplish the same thing using [`xclip`](https://github.com/astrand/xclip):

```bash
$ alias xclip='xclip -selection clipboard'
$ github-markup README.md | xclip
```

Many other Linux clipboard utilities are available, for example [cb](https://getclipboard.app/).

### Shelling Out From Ruby

You could also run the command-line executable in a Ruby program:

```rb
puts `github-markup README.md`.chomp
```

### Shelling Out From Python

You could also run the command-line executable in a Python program:

```py
import os
print(os.system('github-markup README.md'))
```